# How to fix an Incompatible pointer for subclass of UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell, incomplete-type

I've implemented a subclass `SPCell` of `UICollectionViewCell` which I am using to create cells in my `UICollectionViewController`. Now, when I gather a cell, in order to do something with it, I get a warning `Incompatible pointer types initializing 'SPCell *' with an expression of type 'UICollectionViewCell *'`

Here is an example. My custom cell holds an image, which I want to change the alpha value. But in the line, where I assign the cell, I get this warning.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;{  
    SPCell *cell = [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.thumbnail.alpha=0.6;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SPCell *cell = (SPCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to add a cast to let the compiler know what you are doing -

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didHighlightItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;{  
    SPCell *cell = (SPCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.thumbnail.alpha=0.6;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I thought it is not necessary, since `SPCell` implements a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell`. But works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: No, you can safely assign a subclass instance to a superclass variable - `UICollectionViewCell *cell=mySPCellInstance` as all `UICollectionViewCell` methods and properties will be available.  You cannot assign a superclass to a subclass variable as the subclass properties & methods may not be available - If you include the cast then the compiler trusts you (although things will blow up at runtime if you get it wrong)